# Determining the best seed for a PRNG to approach a value

Tags: random

Is there a practical/realistic way for a Mersenne twister (or another PRNG, if you deem it more appropriate) to have their seed selected to approach a 10MB large number as close as possible in less than 20 seconds on modern hardware?

So one would look at the number and tell, "take this seed, it's the best one to approach that number, given the number of bits".

Except a brute force approach of course, which is infeasible for the game (level generator) I am finalizing.